# What happen with this matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ochl code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Have no idea about the error.
The csv file is from pd.datareader. ButI think it's not about datareader. the csv file i used is exported mouths ago, and it's complete.I think it's something wrong with "candlestick2_ochl()" function

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1538, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 280, in resize
>       self.show()
>     File "C:\Python34..................

```
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ochl
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    style.use('ggplot')

    df = pd.read_csv('tsla.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
    df['100ma'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()

    df = df.reset_index()
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(mdates.date2num)
    print(df.head())             

    ft = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
    ax1.xaxis_date()
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)


    candlestick2_ochl( ax1,df['Open'], df['Adj Close'], df['High'], df['Low'], width=.75, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)

    ax1.plot(df['Date'], df['100ma'])
    ax2.bar(df['Date'], df['Volume'])

    plt.show()
```

Comment: can you post some of the data, so we can test this?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably broken since Yahoo has updated its API. pandas_datareader will not work any more

As a temporary fix, you can download the fix-yahoo-finance package to get this to work again. You should be able to pip install this package,

```
pip install fix-yahoo-finance
```

Then just import the fix-yahoo-finance and re-rerun.

Comment: No, I think it's not about datareader. the csv file i used is exported mouths ago, and it's complete.I think it's something wrong with "candlestick2_ochl()" function.