# Is Yahoo! quote retrieval with matplotlib working for recent years?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This works:

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc
date1 = (2004, 2, 1)
date2 = (2004, 4, 12)
quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc('INTC', date1, date2)
```

But this does not:

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc
date1 = (2017, 2, 1)
date2 = (2017, 4, 12)
quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc('INTC', date1, date2)
```

The only difference is 2017 versus 2004. I know that Yahoo! has made some changes recently. I am on mpl version 1.5.1. Do I need to update mpl, or is it something else?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 451, in quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc
    ochl=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 499, in _quotes_historical_yahoo
    fh = fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, date1, date2, cachename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 358, in fetch_historical_yahoo
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url)) as urlfh:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
  URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: There have been some changes made to the yahoo data and service. Possibly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616963/what-happen-with-this-matplotlib-finance-candlestick2-ochl-code) may help you.

Comment: yahoo API has been deprecated. Sorry :(